# Database - MS SQL - Lottery game -

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I read a few answers in stackoverflow. But still have question.
I want to write something like lottery game.

In design - User can choose game. And buy ticket.
Now  user can buy a lot of tickets. Let's say user can buy 1000-2000 tickets.
(50 games * 40 ticekts for example)
No I just think about case when I have 1M users and each one buy 2K tickets 
(I know its sound like unpossible case, but want to check everythink before going to production)

1M users * 2K tickets each user = 2B tickets.

Right now I have table like:

```
Id | UserId | GameId | TicketId | IsActive | TimeInsert
```

UserId and Gameid - is index

And today i do row for each ticket. Its mean in case of 2B ticekts - i will have 2B rows.

In my design ticket has uniq number -- and user can cancel/delete 1 specif ticket.

---

Question:
I understand that 2B rows in database - not good. (very bad))))

Question - What is the best practice to store data like this.

One of option that I see its to store
Its store tickets in BLOB.
For example
50 games * 40 tickets ===>
50 rows. and in BLOB store 40 tickets.

P.S Sorry  for my English grammar.

Comment: Typically, a lottery issues a fixed number of tickets. The tickets that are actually issued will need to be tracked -- individually. No lottery I know of would actually issue 2 billion tickets per game, so that's not a concern. Total number of tickets, not how many tickets a user buys, is the important factor. Having 50 different games going on simultaneously also seems improbable. Even *if* you had to store 2 billion rows, though -- so what? I maintain a database with a table containing over 6 billion rows.

Comment: Thank you. I write code on C#. So the best way is write SQL query (ADO .NET) and not use any ORM, right?

Comment: Go with simple solution and it is one ticket per row. It is what the databases are built for and they are optimized for that. By bundling data into blobs you will make your life terrible. Just imagine how would you select from that data. No index will help you with that. And if you will really hit the wall, then there is still [partitioning](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/) in SQL Server. So I wouldn't worry about that. As documentation says limit for rows is available storage.

Comment: @MaxA: that doesn't follow at all from your question and is an entirely separate issue. "Best" is a useless term on its own. Best in terms of what? Development speed? Raw performance? Maintainability? Nothing will beat hand-written code using `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` in terms of performance, but ORMs exist for a reason.

Comment: With direct SQL you have more control on what you are doing especially when you use database created by someone else but have to be careful about SQL injection and other issues. With ORM I sometimes see crazy things like reading same data three times and sometimes it is hard to convince it to do what you want. ORMs try to make your life easier, and most of the time they do. But we are getting little bit off topic here.

Comment: Guys - THANK YOU!!!!!! So i will keep in row per ticket way - and will do stress test about 5B-10B-20B rows and will see time results.
Thank you - very helpfully and so fast.

Comment: 1 more question is - SQL Standart is enough or I MUST go to enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

With a narrow table like that, I would go ahead and store one row per ticket.   2B rows isn't that bad in a narrow table.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.